# Solve integral $\int 12\sin x\cos x\sqrt[4]{3\sin^2 x+e^8}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I hope you are well.

Thanks if you can solve this question and explain the solution method.

$$
\int 12\sin x\cos x\sqrt[4]{3\sin^2 x+e^8}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Thank you all

Comment: It is suggested that you add your attempts, even if they’re wrong

Comment: Try $u=3\sin^2 x+e^8$.

Comment: This is the kind of question to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let: $u=3sin^2(x)+e^8$, this means: $du=6sin(x)cos(x)dx$. Therefore:

$\int 12\sin x\cos x\sqrt[4]{3\sin^2 x+e^8}dx
=2\int(3sin^2(x)+e^8)^{1/4}(6sin(x)cos(x))dx
=2\int u^{1/4}du
=\frac85u^{5/4}+C
=\frac85(3sin^2(x)+e^8)^{5/4}+C$